# what is the Azure CLI command to add https listener in application gateway from key-vault (Cert)?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to add listener to application gateway using Azure CLI command (type as HTTPs) and cert is available in Key-vault. I tried from documentation but ended up with confusion. Can anyone let me know azure cli command for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following script. I run the script in Azure cloud shell.

1. create a user-managed identity

```
objId=$(az identity create -g $groupName  -n $msiName --query 'principalId' -o json)
```

2. configure access policy for the msi

```
az keyvault set-policy -n $vaultName --secret-permissions get --object-id $objId
```

3. assign msi to the application gateway

```
az network application-gateway identity assign --identity $msiName -g $groupName  --gateway-name $appgwName
```

4. create ssl cert in application gateway

```
#configure access policy for the account you log in if the account haa no permissions
az keyvault set-policy -n $vaultName --certificate-permissions  create get import list  --upn "<>"
ssl=$(az keyvault certificate show -n test --vault-name $vaultName --query 'sid'  -o json)
#remove the version form cert url
ssl=$(echo ${ssl:1:-1})
sslurl=$(dirname $ssl)
#create ssl
(az network application-gateway ssl-cert create -n mysslcet -g $groupName --gateway-name $appgwName --key-vault-secret-id $sslurl)
```

5. Create forted port

```
az network application-gateway frontend-port create  -g $groupName --gateway-name $appgwName -n <port name> --port 448
```

6. create HTTP lister

```
az network application-gateway http-listener create  -n MyHttpListener12 -g $groupName --gateway-name $appgwName --frontend-port <port name> --frontend-ip <appGwPublicFrontendIp name> --ssl-cert <the name of SSL cert you create>
```

[image]

Comment: A valid Key Vault URI should be in the following format: _https://{keyvaultname}.{keyvaultdomain}/secrets/{secretname}_.
After getting the certificate you have to replace the _certificates_ folder by _secrets_ in `sslurl`.